# ListView.View is null in dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to disable column reording in a control we have created that is derived from ListView. This control is called a `SortableListView`. I thought a dependency property would be the best way to implement this, but the `((SortableListVIew)source).View` is returning `null`. Here is the code:

```
public class SortableListView : ListView
{
    // ...lots of other properties here

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AllowsColumnReorderProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
          "AllowsColumnReorder", 
          typeof(bool), 
          typeof(SortableListView), 
          new UIPropertyMetadata(true, AllowsColumnReorderPropertyChanged));

    public bool AllowsColumnReorder
    {
        get
        {
            return (bool)this.GetValue(AllowsColumnReorderProperty);
        }

        set
        {
            this.SetValue(AllowsColumnReorderProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void AllowsColumnReorderPropertyChanged(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ViewBase vb = ((SortableListView)source).View;

        if (vb != null)
        {
            ((GridView)vb).AllowsColumnReorder = (bool)e.NewValue;  
        }
    }
```

And the XAML:

```
    <TableControls:SortableListView x:Name="QueueViewTable" Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                      Style="{StaticResource ListViewStyle}"
                                      ItemsSource="{Binding Path=QueueList}"
                                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource alternatingListViewItemStyle}"
                                      AlternationCount="2"
                                      SelectionMode="Single"
                                      SortEnabled="False"
                                      AllowsColumnReorder="false">
```

The trouble is that vb is always null so the method fails to set AllowsColumnReoder. I am quite sure that the cast is valid because the code originally looked like this in OnInitialized:

```
    ((GridView)this.View).AllowsColumnReorder = false;
```

...but I need to set the AllowsColumnReorder on a particular instance of the view so this code is no good.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or is there a better way to set this property?

Answer (score 0):

The `View` property of `ListView` is itself a dependency property that could change.  It appears to not be set *yet* when you're setting your property?

You may have to override the `View` property in your sortable list view, so you can add a property change listener, and then apply your sort property when the view itself gets set?

in wpf, you can override a dependency property declared in a parent class, shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754209.aspx

you'd override the metadata for the `View` property, and in the `PropertyMetadata` param you set there, you can pass a function like you are above for `AllowsColumnReorderPropertyChanged`

in that handler, you'd check to see if the new view is a gridview, and then set your property.

that way, the either order of `AllowsColumnReorder` or `View` getting set will properly set your property.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. How do I override the View property and add a change listener? Sorry for the dumb question but I'm fairly new to WPF and am learning on the job.

Comment: Many thanks for the info John. I have one more question though: how do I get the correct paramanter for my AlowsColumnReorderPropertyChanged method?

Comment: not sure what you mean.  what correct parameter are you trying to get?